# Remove bottom margin on image in product description with css?

Tags: css, woocommerce, whitespace

I added “add to cart” button image over which I have put a link to checkout, image is located on top of my product description but spacing between image and text is too great... This is the code I used to remove bottom margin (I used inspect element and unchecked bottom margin and it looked perfect)

```
<img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-623" src="(your image url)" alt="" width="383" height="70" />
<ul>
    <li>FREE WORLDWIDE SHIPPING</li>
    <li>Delivery time: 9 to 18 days</li>
</ul>

<style>
img {
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}
li,
ul {
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
  line-height: 8px !important;
}
</style>
```

Bottom margin is definitely a source of problem. I'm using SiteOrigin CSS plugin to edit my css but code above is not working as expected, [you can see how it looks with code above and when I uncheck bottom margin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/moCLe.png) with inspect element (text is deformed as well even when I delete text part of the code).

And [here you can see how the code looks before and after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gN5E.png) it's saved in SiteOrigin CSS (got some errors as well).

Comment: Can you provide us a minimal working snippet with the img ?

Comment: try `display: block` on `img` tag

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As you already said: "SiteOrigin CSS plugin" is the thing you are using.

But all tags with "<" and ">" are HTML tags and have nothing to do with CSS (Cascading **Style** Sheets). HTML is a markup languages which defines the markup and NOT the design.

EDIT: Try this code and remove everything you just posted.

```
img.size-full.alignnone{
  margin-bottom: inherit;
}
```

tl;dr; You placed HTML Code in a CSS plugin. Remove it!

Comment: CSS is inside `<style>` tags. This is perfectly valid.

Comment: Yes, but this Wordpress plugin is for CSS only! You can not place HTML tags in a CSS plugin... Thats why the parser is recognizing errors. Resource: https://wordpress.org/plugins/so-css/

Comment: You‘re welcome. But still no clue why people downvote my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
img.size-full.alignnone {
      margin: 0;
      margin-bottom: 0px;
    }
    li,
    ul {
      margin: 0;
      margin-bottom: 0px;
      line-height: 8px !important;
    }
```

Comment: `margin-bottom` takes a measurement value, not a color value